# Maya texture is displaying a faded edge when there is none

Tags: 3d, textures, maya

I thought I'd try even if this isn't so much code or maybe there is a python or mel solution.

In Maya, I have a 2 separate polygons. Each polygon has a texture. The two textures were infact one texture which I split into two. In photoshop, there isn't a seam, everything looks normal.

But using a lambert to load the file into maya, a grey edge appears. My guess its <5 pixel border, but its coming into the image so I can't simply move the uv as I would lose data from the texture. No UV wrap, and no mirror UV. I can't use mirror UV as our subsequent process doesn't recognise mirror UV.

I can't do any baking of the sorts.

Anybody have an idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I concluded that the issue occurs with maya's mip mapping which causes the grey edge. The only solution was to combine the texture to form a larger texture. Then selecting each set of UV, changing the origin to align with a corner of choosing and scaling down. Merge any UV down the seam lines, and wa la, seamless surface.